# Make image from image url (Laravel)

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, intervention

I have image in my public/uploads/images folder and I have to send this image as a file object to API.
I have tried with 
**new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile($filePath);**
and with this
**new File($filePath);**
but nothing worked for me.

I need response to be something like this!

```
image" => UploadedFile {#27 ▼
                -test: false
                -originalName: "58556f1e6784680a0b37ad690.5879949284717441.jpg"
                -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
                -size: 45909
                -error: 0
              }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should check how that API gets the file. Often they get files in byte array and maybe need some other options in header of request.